# Iterable.generate: Iterable<Future<String>> throws Exception

Tags: dart

Just playing with Dart: Do you know why this is not working?
I just want to be able to run through an Iterable of Futures.

```
import 'dart:async';

Iterable<Future<String>> getFutureIterataleData(int sec) {
  var iterable = new Iterable.generate(5);
  iterable.map(
    (n) =>  Future<String>((){return "Hello";})).iterator;
  return iterable;
  }

main() {
  Stream<String> streamS = new Stream.fromFutures(getFutureIterataleData(5));
  streamS.listen((data) {
    print(data);
  });

  print("Done");
}
```

It throws the following Exception:

```
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_GeneratorIterable<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Future<String>>')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [map method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) returns a new lazy Iterable with elements that are created by calling the function argument on each element of the Iterable in iteration order. You instead return the original `iterable`.

Also You have to return an iterable, not an iterator, so do not apply the `iterator` getter.

```
Iterable<Future<String>> getFutureIterataleData(int sec) {
  var iterable = new Iterable.generate(5);

  return iterable.map(
    (n) =>  Future<String>((){return "Hello";}));

  }
```